# Atmosphere: The method getDefault() from the type BroadcasterFactory is deprecated

Tags: atmosphere

I'm using Atmosphere 2.2.0-RC3. And I have this warning: "The method getDefault() from the type BroadcasterFactory is deprecated" in the line **BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(topic, true)**
Here is the code:

```
@Path("/chat/{topic}")
@AtmosphereService (broadcaster = JerseyBroadcaster.class)
public class ChatResourceTopic {

    private @PathParam("topic")
    String topic;   

    @Suspend( contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, listeners = { OnDisconnect.class })
    @GET
    public Broadcastable suspend()  {
        return new Broadcastable(BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(topic, true ));
    }
    ...
}
```

I have checked the wiki and is widely used: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Understanding-Broadcaster

**How could I change the code to avoid the warning?**

Note: I also use this in:
BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(topic).broadcast(response);

Comment: The Atmosphere Project has put an entry in its wiki and solve it by injection like @baldy says in his answer (Getting BroadcasterFactory and AtmosphereResourceFactory with 2.2 and newer): https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-BroadcasterFactory-and-AtmosphereResourceFactory-with-2.2-and-newer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Jersey with Atmosphere (I use `@ManagedService`) but you should be able to inject either an `AtmosphereResource` or `BroadcasterFactory` with the `@Context` annotation when you use Jersey.

```
public Broadcastable suspend(@Context BroadcasterFactory factory) {
```

OR

```
public Broadcastable suspend(@Context AtmosphereResource resource) {
    BroadcasterFactory factory = resource.getAtmosphereConfig().getBroadcasterFactory();
```

I have not tested this but it's in older [documentation](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Injecting-Atmosphere's-Components-in-Jersey)

Comment: But I have a piece of code outside this jersey class where I use it and I'm not able to inject there.
If there is a warning for deprecated, I guess that they have offered another way to do it within the API

Comment: I haven't found any other way to obtain either the `BroadcasterFactory` or the `AtmosphereConfig` which is what you really want anyway other than by injection. In my code, I'm passing the `AtmosphereConfig` object to a method in my injected object and saving it there. Since there is no need for a `Broadcaster` until the first client connects, I just ignore any events until after the first client connect. I agree it's not ideal but it works.

Comment: In the link to the Atmosphere wiki given by tainos, says that: "If you're using the atmosphere-jersey extension, you can have jersey inject BroadcasterFactory with a context parameter"

Comment: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-BroadcasterFactory-and-AtmosphereResourceFactory-with-2.2-and-newer